# Enumerator Type not recognised in interface

Tags: objective-c, xcode, enums

I have a header (@interface) in which I declared a enumerator.

I'm referencing that enumerator's type as a parameter for my initWithDelegate constructor, but XCode doesn't see it as a valid type.

I'd appreciate some advice on this.

Here's the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ReportLoader : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* fileKey;

//Issue with this line at the pReportType parameter declaration.
-(NSObject*)initWithDelegate:(NSObject*)pDelegate andService:(ServiceReference*)pService andFileKey:(NSString*)pKey andReportType:(ReportType)pReportType;

typedef enum ReportTypes
{
    GridReport = 1,
    TableReport = 2,
    FlowReport = 3,
}ReportType;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `typdef` for your enum, there isn't way to declare forward declaration (like you use `@class` for classes declared later).

The simplest way to solve this problem is to put enum definition on top, above the functions where you use it.